# How would you find the most common word in a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function that takes a dictionary as a parameter and returns a key whose value is the longest by iterating over the dictionary. If the dictionary is empty it should return an empty string. If there is a tie for the word with the longest list of positions then the function may return any one of the common words.

For example:

```
>>> {'He': [0], 'thought': [1, 5, 6], 'it': [2], 'was': [3], 'chicken': [4]} 
Output: thought
```

It must return the most common word based on the positions.

However I think I get the idea but I instead a wrote a function that returns the maximum value:

```
def commonest(dct):
    max_length = 0
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if len(val) >= max_length:
            max_key = key
    return max_key
```

So instead of returning "thought" it returns "chicken".
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to update `max_length` aswell:

```
def commonest(dct):
    max_length = 0
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if len(val) >= max_length:
            max_key = key
            max_length = len(val)
    return max_key
```

Comment: Makes sense! Haha silly mistake. How would it return an empty string if I tested it with an empty dictionary? Would I use a while loop? Saying while the condition is not equal to an empty dict?

Comment: Actually nevermind i mean an if-statement. I wanted to make sure it was pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max` function over the dict items with a key function that returns the length of the sub-list:

```
max(dct.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1]))[0]
```

This returns: `thought`